# How to use font-icons created by icomoon in create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, sass, icons, create-react-app

I converted svg to font-icons using icomoon and imported the generated font files in index.scss of create-react-app but **sometime** these icons don't load up in the application and look like this
[Broken Icons Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sl7aH.png)
I tried using preload as well but didn't work.

How to resolve this issue?

We are deploying the app on AWS.

Thank you in advance.

I tried finding a solution over various places but didn't find an optimal solution

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "appicon";
  src: url("./resources/fonts/appicon.woff") format("woff"), url("./resources/fonts/appicon.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("./resources/fonts/appicon.eot") format("embedded-opentype");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a fix for this. thank you everyone for your offline support.

The fix is we need to make sure that font files are not cached and icons used in scss files are decoded first before use.
As decoding on runtime in production environment doesn't convert these variables under content property to valid value

Comment: How did you do that? Meaning ensure that icons used in css file are decoded first?